# Working java code to read the demo Google Sheet in a project?

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

Having tried working with code snippets from various sources and posts, can anyone actually post a complete (with imports) starting-point working java example that can be used within a project, to connect to a demo Google sheet and (at least) read data? This would be good for those looking for a basic working mechanism to play with and tailor further.

For example, based on the Google sample at: 
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java

which aims to get data from the demo Sheet noted in the code:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
```

Jars obtained from: 
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/sheets/v4/java

A 'client_secret.json' file will also need to be generated, as per Google's instructions, and made available to the project.

What looks like the most comprehensive sample so far, I've found on GitHub. (code below) Thanks to Google & jovito-royeca/Hourlify. (It also looks to be able to add data to a sheet, but probably a different bridge to cross)

For me, with the jars and client_secret.json present, when running the code I am returned:

```
May 09, 2017 4:36:10 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\Users\David\.credentials\sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart.json
May 09, 2017 4:36:10 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Users\David\.credentials\sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart.json
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at teamExample.SheetsQuickstart.authorize(SheetsQuickstart.java:70)
    at teamExample.SheetsQuickstart.getSheetsService(SheetsQuickstart.java:93)
    at teamExample.SheetsQuickstart.readSampleSpreadsheet(SheetsQuickstart.java:113)
    at teamExample.SheetsQuickstart.main(SheetsQuickstart.java:105)
```

Full code, adapted slightly from the GitHub repo:

```
/*
 * Sample java to access, read and write data in Google Sheets.
 */
package teamExample;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SheetsQuickstart {
    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
        "Google Sheets API Quickstart";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart.json");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
        JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
     * at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart.json
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in =
            SheetsQuickstartA.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .setApprovalPrompt("force")
                .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Sheets API client service.
     * @return an authorized Sheets API client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Sheets getSheetsService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }





    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //createHourlifyEmployees();
        readSampleSpreadsheet();
    }




    public static void readSampleSpreadsheet() throws IOException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        Sheets service = getSheetsService();

        // Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
        // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
        String spreadsheetId = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms";
        String range = "Class Data!A2:E";
        ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
            .get(spreadsheetId, range)
            .execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        if (values == null || values.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No data found.");
        } else {
          System.out.println("Name, Major");
          for (List row : values) {
            // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
            System.out.printf("%s, %s\n", row.get(0), row.get(4));
          }
        }
    }

    public static void createHourlifyEmployees() throws Exception {
        String spreadsheetId = "14oUVpOkT_mcwOIvOn643g7Q_OktdCkdru4NpURMlUhU";
        int employeeCount = 200;
        ArrayList<ValueRange> values = new ArrayList<>();

        List lastNames = arrayFromFile("lastname.csv");
        List firstNames = arrayFromFile("firstname.csv");
        for (int i=0; i<employeeCount; i++) {
            Random rand1 = new Random();
            Random rand2 = new Random();

            ValueRange value = new ValueRange();

            ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList<Object> row = new ArrayList();
            row.add(i+1000);
            row.add(lastNames.get(rand1.nextInt(lastNames.size()-1)));
            row.add(firstNames.get(rand2.nextInt(firstNames.size()-1)));
            arrayList.add(row);

            value.set("values", arrayList);
            value.setRange("Employees!A"+(i+2)+":C"+(i+2));
            values.add(value);
        }

        BatchUpdateValuesRequest request = new BatchUpdateValuesRequest();
        request.setValueInputOption("RAW");
        request.setData(values);
        Sheets service = getSheetsService();
        service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, request).execute();
    }

    public static List<Map<String,String>> generateNames() {
//        List lastNames = arrayFromFile("lastname.csv");
//        List firstNames = arrayFromFile("firstname.csv");
        ArrayList<Map<String,String>> array = new ArrayList();
        int number = 150;

        for (int i=0; i<number; i++) {

        }

        return array;
    }

    public static List<String> arrayFromFile(String fileName) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList();
        InputStream in = SheetsQuickstartA.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            array.add(line);
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

Many thanks. Hopefully this will be useful to others.

Comment: are you asking a question or posting your answer?

Comment: asking a question, and providing sample code if it serves as a useful basis to work from.